# IBM DB2 LUW BOOLEAN and CLI SQLBindParameter for NULL

Tags: db2, boolean, db2-luw, odbc

IBM DB2 LUW 11.1.1.1 introduced the BOOLEAN SQL data type.

Using IBM CLI, I want to pass an SQL parameter as NULL to insert a row in a table with BOOLEAN column, by using the SQLBindParameter() function.

I am using same ODBC calls, flags and buffers as with MS ODBC SQL Server and SAP HANA ODBC.

When using non-NULL values, I can insert TRUE/FALSE in the BOOLEAN column.

Inserting TRUE/FALSE values into my BOOLEAN col works fine when binding:

- 1/0 with SQL_C_SHORT + SQL_SMALLINT

or:

- '1'/'0' with SQL_C_CHAR + SQL_CHAR

But when setting the StrLen_or_IndPtr indicator to SQL_NULL_DATA, I get the following error at statement execution:

[IBM][CLI Driver] CLI0164E  Nullable type out of range. SQLSTATE=HY099

I don't understand why...

Any clue?

Here some SQL to illustrate BOOLEAN type usage with DB2:

```
db2 => create table t1 ( pk int, bl boolean ) 
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
db2 => insert into t1 values ( 101, TRUE )
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
db2 => insert into t1 values ( 102, FALSE )
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
db2 => insert into t1 values ( 103, NULL )
DB20000I  The SQL command completed successfully.
db2 => select * from t1 where bl IS NULL
PK          BL
----------- --
        103 -
   1 record(s) selected.
db2 => select * from t1 where bl
PK          BL
----------- --
        101  1
  1 record(s) selected.
db2 => select * from t1 where bl is true
PK          BL
----------- --
        101  1
  1 record(s) selected.
db2 => select * from t1 where bl is false
PK          BL
----------- --
        102  0
  1 record(s) selected.
```

Comment: bools can't be null.  Simple enough.

Comment: danny117, BOOLEAN columns in SQL can be NULL if you don't specify a NOT NULL constraint.

Comment: I have updated the question text with some SQL to illustrate this.

Comment: Like integers can be null.   NOT

Comment: This was tested with IBM DB2 LUW 11.5 on Debian 9.

Comment: Same problem on Windows with DB2 LUW 11.5

Comment: Are you using the latest Db2 Client level available? If so, you might need to raise a case with IBM Support

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IBM support answered that the bug is known and is fixed in APAR IT30675
Problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

We have 11.5.0.0 client and server installed.

I could reproduce with a simple CLI program.

It appears that it's related to the deferred prepare statement option!

I get the CLI0164E error when using SQL_DEFERRED_PREPARE_OFF:

rcode = SQLSetStmtAttr(m_hstmt, SQL_ATTR_DEFERRED_PREPARE,
                       (SQLPOINTER) SQL_DEFERRED_PREPARE_OFF, 0);

When not using this option, the INSERT executes and NULL can be inserted.

Very strange.

So yes this looks like a DB2 client bug...

We'll open a support case at IBM.